# Wordpress Media Library Acknowledges Images, Doesn't List

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone ever experienced this problem before?
Wordpress is successfully uploading and logging images... it even knows the exact count uploaded. However, the media page refuses to list the individual items.

[image]

Very Stange. Any ideas?!
Note: I've eliminated plugins as a possible problem. Could it be a table in the database with an incorrect url?

Thanks!

Comment: what wp version ? can you describe you exact steps to reproduce this problem ? can you reproduce it with a new install ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your media uploads directory after uploading files, but not move any of the files? It looks like either a 404 sort of error, or a corrupt database that has lost the data (And only has the meta information about uploads)

One more thing I'd check is that apache has full read/write access to appropriate media folders. E.g in Ubuntu,

```
chown www-data /home/public_html/website/wp-content/uploads -R
```